# opencart sitemap crawl errors on webmaster tools

Tags: url, opencart, sitemap, google-search-console

I keep getting crawl errors on webmaster tools for my opencart website for old urls even though the sitemap is dynamically updated. I've tried resubmitting the sitemap as soon as i make url updates but this doesn't seem to help either.

example error url: www.imbued.co.uk/george-nelson-inspired-coconut-chair
sitemap: www.imbued.co.uk/sitemap.xml

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "old urls"?

Comment: @VinceKronlein Meaning urls that no longer exist due to page being removed or change of url

Comment: That sounds like a google problem. Your sitemap looks good, so I don't think the problem lies there.